# Why do I get a 500 error when running a CGI from `public_html`, when it works with a python CGI server?

Tags: python, cgi

> **Summary:** Python cgi script runs as expected when called from a simple python debug server, but fails with `500 Premature end of script headers` error when run from `~/public_html/cgi-bin/`

### Problems

My CGI script works fine when run through a simple python webserver, and I see the right output when navigating to `nameofmyhost.com:8080/...`

However, when running the same script from my `public_html/cgi-bin` directory it gives me a `500 premature end of script headers` error. What can I do to fix this?

The permissions on the file seem ok:

```
drwxrwxrwx   cgi-bin
-rwxr-xr-x   cgi-bin/generate_list.py
```

This is simple_httpd.py, the simple python webserver

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler

port = 8080

httpd = HTTPServer(('', port), CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
print("Starting simple_httpd on port: " + str(httpd.server_port))
httpd.serve_forever()
```

CGI script generate_list.py:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/python3
import athletemodel
import yate
import glob

data_files = glob.glob("data/*.txt")
athletes = athletemodel.put_to_store(data_files)

print(yate.start_response())
print(yate.include_header("Coach Kelly's List of Athletes"))
print(yate.start_form("generate_timing_data.py"))
print(yate.para("Select an athlete from the list to work with:"))

for each_athlete in athletes:
    print(yate.radio_button("which_athlete", athletes[each_athlete].name))
print (yate.end_form("Select"))

print(yate.include_footer({"Home": "/index.html"}))
```

I'm guessing I need to maybe explicitly state my directory somewhere, maybe?

PS: I am going through the Head First Python book by Oreilly

### Debugging steps

1. Check that the server can locate my files

   Server finds simple html file in public_home **[OK]**
2. Check that the CGI script can execute without error.

   ```
       Content-type: text/html 

       <html> 
       <head> 
       <title>Coach Kelly's List of Athletes</title>
       [...]
   ```

   CGI script ran from command line - outputs as expected **[OK]**
3. Check that the server can execute a simple CGI script in the same location

   Try a simple CGI script to see if the server is able to execute any CGI scripts *at all*:

   ```
       #!/usr/local/bin/python3
       print("Content-Type; text/html")
       print("")
       print("<html><body><h1>hello</h1></body></html>")
   ```

   Server fails to execute simple CGI script, giving the same error **[FAIL]**

### Fixes

**Fix 1:** Change the data path to be absolute instead of relative:

```
- data_files = glob.glob("data/*.txt")
+ data_files = glob.glob("/home/delliott/public_html/webapp/data/*.txt")
```

Comment: you'll need to provide actual code here

Comment: The question does not contain anywhere near enough info to be answered. -1 please edit for clarity and provide relevant code.

Comment: i added the code, and tried to explain more at the end. If I can answer anything else let me know.

Comment: that will make it easier to debug FunBeans. Removed my downvote. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the base of your school webserver is not the same as the base of the `simple_httpd.py` server. This means that you will have to provide absolute paths to your data directory instead of relative paths.

Change the following lines:

```
- data_files = glob.glob("data/*.txt")
+ data_files = glob.glob("/home/<username>/public_html/data/*.txt")
```

This should now behave as expected (if I understand your problem correctly.)

[Edit]: A quick way to check if your cgi-bin scripts work is to run them from the command line. Log into your school server and try the cgi script ion its own:

```
$ cd /home/<username>/public_html/
$ python3 my_cgi_script.py
```

This should print out the html that you expect, or a stack trace.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the path and then I checked my script from the command line and it had some errors, but it was because i had to adjust the path in another file, which I did and then finally it printed out the HTML page. But I'm still getting the 500 error. premature end of script headers.

Comment: FunBeans: I don't expect line 18 is the problem. You can remove it to check. Would you put up the first four lines of output from your cgi script? Would you also run `ls -lR` for your `webapp` folder? It might be a weird ownership mismatch between cgi-bin and the script.

Comment: You can also try a very simple script to test whether the CGI infrastructure works as expected. `print("Content-Type: text/html\n\n<h1>Hello</h1>\n")` in a python script in the same location as your athlete list should execute successfully when called from a webpage.

Comment: `Content-type: text/html`


`<html>`
`<head>`
`<title>Coach Kelly's List of Athletes</title>`

Comment: I put the permissions in my question at the very end. I also made the small test script saved it as test.py and put it in index.html and it gave the same 500 error.

Comment: `test.py` seems not to have executable permission set. (-rw-r--r--) does it change anything if you do `chmod a+x cgi-bin/test.py`? Also, could you confirm if there is an empty line between the Content-Type header and the rest of the output? -- I'm going to edit the question to make it shorter for readability.

Comment: changed permissions. test.py works when I do the port number. but still not my directory structure. And theres two lines from the generate4.py when I run it using python3 from the command line.

Thanks for helping edit my question. I'm a little concerned that this problem is just the school server being finicky, as its been known to be when you try doing something outside of what is explicitly known to work (i.e. php) but I thought a lot of people used python around her and i figured it was installed on the server should be able to learn some python web development using my account.

Comment: Hey FunBeans, it certainly is looking that way. The simple python script should work without problem. Perhaps with a different shebang line: `#!/usr/bin/env python`? I'm out of ideas after that...